# HTML ON-CLICK EVENT

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html >
    <head>
        <title>scripting </title>
        <script type ="text/JavaScript">
        function add() {
            alert("well come to JavaScript");
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="fr">
            <input id="click me" type="button" value="click me" name="button"
            on-click="add()">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my code but I got some problem with `on-click` event it is not calling my `add()` function. How to call it?

Comment: onclick instead of on-click

Answer (score 2):

The event name is `onclick` not `on-click` :

```html
<html >
 <head>
  <title>scripting </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form name="fr">
   <input id="click me" type="button" value="click me" name="button"
   onclick="add()">
  </form>
        <script type ="text/JavaScript">
  function add() {
   alert("well come to JavaScript");
  }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i try both on-click & onclick

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `on-click` write `onclick`.

Comment: i try both on-click & onclick

Comment: Try to run the code snippet from [Thom-x](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31604898/2806832)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="click me" type="button" value="click me" name="button"
            onclick="add()">
```

note

```
onclick="add()"
```

Comment: i try both on-click & onclick

Comment: @SachinPatil  Try this : `<input id="click me" type="button" value="click me" name="button">` (delete onclick) then in javascript script put `var inputclick=document.getElementByid("clickme"); inputclick.onclick = function(){add();};`